# How to convert this HSV into RGB

Tags: python, opencv

How to convert this HSV into RGB I would like it using cv2.color cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB but its not same result.

This is the image i've used
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH6PT.jpg)

Heres' the result that I want but using the cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB but the code below is using the cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOczJ.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

## Read
img = cv2.imread("ni.jpg")

## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
# mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (7, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))

## slice the green
imask = mask>0
green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[imask] = img[imask]

## save 
cv2.imwrite("green.png", green)
```

Comment: I can't see where you try to convert HSV to RGB or BGR. Where is that code? Also what does _not same result mean_?

Comment: Sorry, ill edit my post.

Comment: I don't really get it. The current code is extracting some greenish-yellowish colors into a mask. What part of your code do you want to _replace_ or _change_?

Comment: cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV to cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB but same result in my post.

Comment: What is the motivation? You do not want to work on a HSV image, but on a RGB image and still be able to _filter_ based on color? Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes right there.

Comment: Still lacking the _why_. But working based on a color-tint is not possible in RGB color space. You have to use HSV or any other color space that has the tint or hue available. So why do you want to use RGB?

Comment: I just want to get the RGB values if that HSV is converted into RGB

Comment: But `img` is still BGR. And how to convert HSV to BGR or RGB has already been answered. So what is your problem?

Comment: Above you have lined a _result that I want_. Maybe share the _result that you get_ and we understand what the problem is?

Comment: let's say I've used this method cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR , now it has a noises when i used this method.

Answer (score 2):

To convert an image from HSV to RGB you can do:

```
rgb = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)
```

and to do HSV to BGR it is

```
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

You have to know that OpenCV is using BGR when reading/saving images.
You can convert between RGB and BGR with cvtColor and cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR, or cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB.

**EDIT:**

However, if what you want is having a mask of green bananas (or yellow bananas), The issue is the way you defined green color : it is including a lot of other colors right now, including yellow.

What you can do with the HSV, is to only look at the first channel, the hue :

[image: Hue of bananas]

Here you can see that green and yellow can be differentiated : green bananas have pixel value roughly between 30 and 50, and yellow between 20 and 30.

You can do a mask with that. I used another library to do the cleanup of pixel we don't want. It is Scikit-image. This can be done in OpenCV as well, but it takes a bit more time...

SO here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import remove_small_objects, remove_small_holes
## Read
img = cv2.imread("ni.jpg")

## convert to hsv
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
hue = hsv[:,:,0]

# plt.imshow(hue) # this show the figure in my post
# plt.show()

# mask = np.bitwise_and(hue > 20, hue < 35) # for yellow
mask = np.bitwise_and(hue > 30, hue < 50)  # for green
mask = remove_small_objects(mask, 1000)
mask = remove_small_holes(mask, 1000)

green = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
green[mask] = img[mask]

## save
cv2.imwrite("green.png", green)
```

Comment: I tried that also but the results is not giving me correctly.

Comment: @Bravos I edited my answer. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: Nope, as you can in this method hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) right? if you change the method cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB that result is not exactly the same, what I want is use this method  cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB

Comment: @Bravos Of course the result is not exactly the same. The channels are reversed, why would you expect them to produce the same results? It appears that the only difference between your input and output images in the question is that the background has been changed to black. What, precisely, are you attempting to achieve?